# Change dot selected color in TabLayout when slide between views

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm using a tablayout with a dot indicator like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp">

tab_selector
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_dot"
        android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_dot"/>
</selector>
```

selected_dot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="4dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

default_dot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="4dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The dots work fine.

That I want to do is change the color of selected dot programmatically when I change of tab according with the background of the activity.

Example:
Activity1 background White selected dot black
Activity2 background yellow selected dot white
Activity3 background red selected dot white

How can I do this??? I'm searching some days about this and try a lot of solutions but any works for me

I'm trying to do it work in on

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
.
.
.
```

MainActivity

```
package com.codingdemos.tablayout;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PageAdapter pageAdapter;
    private static final int SELECTED_COLOR = Color.GREEN;
    private static final int UNSELECTED_COLOR = Color.GRAY;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, true);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                changeTabViewDotColor(tab, true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                changeTabViewDotColor(tab, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    }

    private void changeTabViewDotColor(TabLayout.Tab tab, boolean isSelected) {
        LayerDrawable backgroundDrawable = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_dot);
        GradientDrawable dotDrawable = (GradientDrawable) backgroundDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.item_dot);
        dotDrawable.setColor(isSelected ? SELECTED_COLOR : UNSELECTED_COLOR);

        try {
            Object tabView = tab.view; //Cannot resolver symbol
            Field field = tab.getClass().getDeclaredField("baseBackgroundDrawable");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(tab, backgroundDrawable);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tabLayout.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.codingdemos.tablayout"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
}
```

Comment: I don't get your point, you already define color states when user select/deselect a tab. Why do you want to change the color again when user change the tab?

Comment: because my selector dot is white and I have an activity all white, then the selected dot is not showing, and in this screen I want to put it black

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/tablayout"
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
app:tabGravity="center"
app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp">


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_dot"
    android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_dot"
    android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/default_dot"/> //you have to mention both dots here
</selector>
```

put this in your code .I noticed you havnt put the default dot code in the selector file.
just put this and run it.you are welcome.

Comment: Hi, sorry dude. I rewrite my question. I want to change the dot selected depends of the activity background color